# Will the frustrated total internal reflection occur if the third medium is a metal?

Tags: optics, reflection, quantum-optics

What would happen if i set up a frustrated total internal reflection experiment with a metal as the material close to the interface? Would radiation energy be transmitted to it and undergo attenuation (turn into heat) or would there be a reflection from the metal, or maybe instead i would just get a total internal reflection without energy transfer through the gap into the metal?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer in wikipedia, see below: ( it's all probability i.e. QM)

Under ordinary conditions, the evanescent wave transmits zero net energy across the interface. However, if a third medium with a higher refractive index than the low-index second medium is placed within less than several wavelengths distance from the interface between the first medium and the second medium, the evanescent wave will be different from the usual one, and it will pass energy across the second into the third medium. (See evanescent wave coupling.) This process is called "frustrated" total internal reflection (FTIR) and is very similar to quantum tunneling. The quantum tunneling model is mathematically analogous if one thinks of the electromagnetic field as being the wave function of the photon. The low index medium can be thought of as a potential barrier through which photons can tunnel.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question; i know already what Frustrated TIR is.

Comment: With a metal it will depend on wavelength, index pf refraction and absorption coefficient to determine the probability of reflection and absorption, what's absorbed turns into heat.